# While rendering a component it is showing an error- "Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`EventList`). "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, setstate

I Can't render my events. Its showing this error -
"Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`EventList`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `EventList`, follow the stack trace as described in [https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render"](https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render%22)

Here is EventList Component code -

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import EventList from "../../event-list";
import EventForm from "../event-form";

const EventAction = ({
    getEventsByClockID,
    addEvent,
    updateEvent,
    clockID,
    deleteEvent,
    deleteEventsByClockID,
}) => {
    const [isCreate, setIsCreate] = useState(false);
    const [isToggle, setIsToggle] = useState(false);
    const [eventState, setEventState] = useState(null)

    const handleCreate = () => {
        setIsCreate(!isCreate);
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setEventState(getEventsByClockID(clockID, true));
    }, [isToggle])

    const handleToggle = () => {
        setIsToggle(!isToggle);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleCreate}>Create Event</button>
                <button onClick={handleToggle}>Toggle Events</button>
            </div>
            {isCreate && (
                <>
                    <h3>Create Event</h3>
                    <EventForm
                        clockID={clockID}
                        handleEvent={addEvent}
                    />
                </>
            )}
            {isToggle && (
                <>
                    <h3>Events of this clock</h3>
                    <EventList 
                        clockID={clockID}
                        eventState={eventState}
                        deleteEvent={deleteEvent}
                        updateEvent={updateEvent}
                        deleteEventsByClockID={deleteEventsByClockID}
                    />
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default EventAction;
```

Here is my App Component Code -

```
import ClockList from "./components/clock-list";
import LocalClock from "./components/local-clock";
import useApp from "./hooks/useApp";
import { localClockInitState } from "./initialStates/clockInitState";

const App = () => {

  const {
    localClock,
    clocks,
    updateLocalClock,
    createClock,
    updateClock,
    deleteClock,
    getEventsByClockID,
    addEvent,
    deleteEvent,
    updateEvent,
    deleteEventsByClockID,
  } = useApp(localClockInitState);

  return (
    <div>
      <LocalClock 
        clock={localClock} 
        updateClock={updateLocalClock} 
        createClock={createClock} 
      />
      <ClockList 
        clocks={clocks}
        localClock={localClock.date}
        updateClock={updateClock} 
        deleteClock={deleteClock}
        getEventsByClockID={getEventsByClockID}
        addEvent={addEvent}
        deleteEvent={deleteEvent}
        updateEvent={updateEvent}
        deleteEventsByClockID={deleteEventsByClockID} 
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

and Here is my useApp hook -

```
import { useState } from "react";
import deepClone from "../utils/deepClone";
import generateID from "../utils/generateId";
import useEvents from "./useEvents";

const getID = generateID('clock');

const useApp = (initValue) => {
  const [localClock, setLocalClock] = useState(deepClone(initValue));
  const [clocks, setClocks] = useState([]);

  const {
    // events,
    // getEvents,
    getEventsByClockID,
    addEvent,
    deleteEvent,
    deleteEventsByClockID,
    updateEvent,
  } = useEvents();

  const updateLocalClock = (data) => {
    setLocalClock({
      ...localClock,
      ...data,
    })
  }

  const createClock = (clock) => {
    clock.id = getID.next().value;
    
    setClocks((prev) => ([
      ...prev, clock
    ]))
  }

  const updateClock = (updatedClock) => {
    setClocks(clocks.map(clock => {
      if(clock.id === updatedClock.id) return updatedClock;

      return clock;
    }));
  }

  const deleteClock = (id) => {
    setClocks(clocks.filter(clock => clock.id !== id));
  }

  return {
    localClock,
    clocks,
    updateLocalClock,
    createClock,
    updateClock,
    deleteClock,
    getEventsByClockID,
    addEvent,
    deleteEvent,
    updateEvent,
    deleteEventsByClockID,
  }
}

export default useApp;
```

I want to show all events incorporated with each individual clock.